# get total by groups for all rows, selected rows and percent of total pandas

Tags: python, pandas

let us say I have a pandas dataframe called mydf.  I.e.,

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.DataFrame({
    'type':['A','A','A', 'B','B','B', 'C'], 
    'state':['NY','CA','NY', 'NY','CA','CA', 'WY'], 
    'date':['2018-01-02','2018-01-04','2018-02-06', 
            '2018-01-01','2018-01-24','2018-02-10','2018-01-24']
})

Out[28]: 
         date state type
0  2018-01-02    NY    A
1  2018-01-04    CA    A
2  2018-02-06    NY    A
3  2018-01-01    NY    B
4  2018-01-24    CA    B
5  2018-02-10    CA    B
6  2018-01-24    WY    C
```

I'd want a table that count total number of records per state and date (year-month only not per daily date) for all records of type A, for all records (type A,B,C) and then the percentage of A within each group to the total.

I.e., the final output would be another pandas dataframe with following columns and values:

```
date_ym state   total_count total_type_A    percentage
20181   CA      2           1               50
20181   NY      2           1               50
20181   WY      1           0               0
20182   CA      1           0               0
20182   NY      1           1               50
```

I could create two tables, then merge them and then count but I was looking for a simpler one-liner code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to create a function that returns a Series with your desired columns.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'type':['A','A','A', 'B','B','B', 'C'], 
    'state':['NY','CA','NY', 'NY','CA','CA', 'WY'], 
    'date':['2018-01-02','2018-01-04','2018-02-06', 
            '2018-01-01','2018-01-24','2018-02-10','2018-01-24']
})

df['date_ym'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y%#m') # switch # with - on linux

def func(x):
    cnt = len(x)
    cnt_A = sum(x == 'A')
    return pd.Series({
        'total_count': cnt,
        'total_type_A': cnt_A,
        'percentage': cnt_A/cnt*100
    })

df = df.groupby(['date_ym','state'])['type'].apply(func).unstack().reset_index()

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  date_ym state  total_count  total_type_A  percentage
0   20181    CA          2.0           1.0        50.0
1   20181    NY          2.0           1.0        50.0
2   20181    WY          1.0           0.0         0.0
3   20182    CA          1.0           0.0         0.0
4   20182    NY          1.0           1.0       100.0
```

Answer (score 2):

First transform dates to months:

```
mydf["date"] = mydf["date"].dt.strftime("%Y%m")
```

Then use [`groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
def total_type_A(x):
    return sum(x == "A")

def percentage(x):
    return sum(x == "A") / len(x)

mydf.groupby(["date", "state"]).agg([len, total_type_A,  percentage])
```

Comment: Tbh, I prefer this solution. I would however use `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y%#m')`.

Comment: @Kopytok thanks.  coding-wise i prefer this solution since it's very clean and clear, but for some reason it performs much slower than the other solution, not sure why.

Comment: @Dnaiel yeah. Maybe it is calling the functions too many times. I think we can speed up by calculating percentages after the other operations are done.